# bash shell code confusion

Tags: bash, shell

The following code recursively find the sub directory of arg1 (pwd by default),labeling each directory or file with a number. Then prompt user to enter a number, and cd that directory label with that number(if it is a directory).

But I do not understand where that number come from....
and how I can control the depth of subdirectory it reaches...

usage
source gd.sh
gd

```
#!/bin/bash

function gd ()
{
local dirname dirs dir

if [ $# -gt 0 ]
then
dirname=$1
else
dirname=$(pwd)
fi

dirs=$(find $dirname -type d)

PS3=`echo -e "\nPlease Select Directory Number: "`

select dir in $dirs
do
if [ $dir ]
then
    cd $dir
    break
else
    echo 'Invalid Selection!'
fi
done
```

Thanks for help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number comes from the `select ... in ...` instruction. It adds a number for each element of the list. Look at the `man` page of `bash`.

For your second question, use the option `-maxdepth` of `find`:

```
dirs=$(find $dirname -maxdepth 2 -type d)
```